# Latex figure at bottom of page for a two column document

Tags: latex, figure

I want to place a figure at the bottom of the current page of my two column document.

Whatever I do, the figure appears always at the bottom of the hole document.

I have to use the pattern listed below... so answers with a different documentclass will not help.

I hope someone has a answer for this problem.

Kind regards

Bud

```
\documentclass[reprint, letterpaper, amsmath, amssymb]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{easybmat}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[figurename=Figure, labelsep=period, font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf, format=plain]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=Justified}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}






% To center table elements vertically 
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\setlength{\parskip}{.1cm}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\date{\today}

\author{XXX$^{1}$}
\author{YY$^{1,2}$}\altaffiliation[Corresponding author ]{}

\affiliation{\vspace{2ex} \makebox[\linewidth][c]{{\normalfont $^1$}Dept. of BlaBla}\\
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{{\normalfont $^2$}Dept. of Blub}\vspace{1ex}\\
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{{\normalfont $^\dagger$}These authors contributed equally to this work}\vspace{1ex}}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\begin{figure*}[!b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Blabla.}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Conclusion}\label{Mechanical model}
\subsection{General design}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 